# Making a dictionary of single key ,multiple values from excel data by dealing with merged cells using xlrd in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, xlrd

I am  using xlrd to extract two columns in an excel file which have around 300 data per sheet.

I have extracted the two columns in two lists and  have made  a dictionary using `dict(zip(list1,list2))`

the problem i am facing is some of the entries in list1 are merged cells so they have multiple values in list2.

sample input is :

```
Request:    4.01
    04.01.01
    04.01.02
    06.01.01
    06.01.04.01
    06.01.04.02
    6.08
```

`Request` is the Key, extracted from column A and all the numbers are values from col B.

How do I make a dictionary in such cases?

Code snippet:

```
file_loc = 'D:/Tool/HC.xlsx'

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_loc)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)


tot_cols = sheet.ncols
tot_rows = sheet.nrows

File_name_list =[]
FD_list=[]
```

Extraction of the values:

```
for row in range(tot_rows):

    new_list =[sheet.cell_value(row,1)]

    File_name_list.append(new_list)  

    new_list2= sheet.cell_value(row,3)
    FD_list.append(new_list2)

dic= dict(zip(File_name_list,FD_list) # Making a dictionary but due to merged cells all the values are not mapped.
```

Comment: I would recommend you export this as csv and parse that.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is indeed coming from merge cells you can unmerge them like explained [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/05/26/unmerge-excel-cells/). But as I said `csv` is a better choice -  more portable and easier to work with (I admit I loathe microsoft stuff). Basically here are the details:

> To get rid of all the merged cells in an Excel 2007 workbook, follow
>   these steps:
>
> - Make a backup copy of the workbook, and store it somewhere safe.
> - Right-click one of the sheet tabs, and click Select All Sheets
> - On the active sheet, click the Select All button, at the top left of the worksheet
> - On the Ribbon's Home tab, click the drop down arrow for Merge & Center
> - Click Unmerge Cells

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Alot  Weasel. Well the problem is my input file is in xlsx and i have to extract two columns from it and make a dictionary .Hence using xlrd to do it. but when i reach merged cells, it only detects one value for the key , in reality there are more than 1 values. Since the KEy is in merged cells this happens. For eg if key is : Keith and  the cell is merged and the values are (2,3,4,5). How to extract and link these two... Kindly Guide me... If its CSV is this possible ?

Comment: in csv format the cells will be separated by a delimiter `,` by default, so it will be easier to handle them as text. you also have python csv library which is very good : https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks.Weasel... I shall  Do it in cSv and get back. I have  no experience with such operations  as  i used to only text file and log file manipulation.Would u recommend any videos. link apart from pydoc for starters. Hope my merged cell issue gets solved..

Comment: @WeaselFox When I convert it in CSV , I lose ll excel formatting and  my merged cells  becoem unmerged .In such cases, How do i  connect two columns with single key and multiple values ?